# How can I make a piece of code loop while a Button is pressed and stop it once the Button is no longer Pressed?

Tags: java, android, button

I am using the android developer tools in Eclipse, programming in Java, and I need to make an object move across the screen as long as a button is pressed.  I've been doing research for hours, and I cannot find any methods to accomplish this.  I've tried running threads, which often crash or seemingly don't execute.  I've also tried an `onClickListener` which reads the button state and uses it to determine whether or not the button is still pressed.  I'm currently using a while loop, but this just freezes the program.  I believe that this is the best method, and I've tried to use Thread.sleep in order to limit the number of iterations per second, as I believe that this is the reason it is freezing. Am I on the right track or am I way off in left field?  Here is a snippet of code:

```
rightButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            while(arg0.isPressed())
            {
                mover.updateCoordinates(1,  0);
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: What crashes exactly, please post logcat also

Comment: your idea of while loop inside button event listener is not good. Revert back to your old thread based code, post the code here and describe where/when it crashes

Comment: On Android, you could use asysnc task also. Have you read this article?
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html

Comment: This doesn't crash, it just freezes.  I also tried calling a recursive method which exits when the button is no longer pressed, but this gave me a stackoverflow error, which I assume means it called itself too many times.

Comment: I tried a thread with this code, but the app crashes as soon as I press the button:

Comment: rightButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
  {
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) 
      {
       Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
             {
              public void run()
              {
               mover.updateCoordinates(1, 0);
              }
             });
          if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
          {  
              t.start();
          } 
          else if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) 
          {
              t.stop();
          }

         return true;
      }
  });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you try this another method?

Firstly declare your button as class variable, declare a Handler and a Runnable:

```
private Button rightButton; // You will assign this in onCreate() method
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(rightButton.isPressed())
        {
            // If press state is pressed, move your item and recall the runnable in 100 milliseconds.
            mover.updateCoordinates(1,  0);
            mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 100);
        }
    }
};
```

Then your button's onClickListener will looks like this:

```
rightButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) 
    {
        // Instead of performing a loop here, just call a runnable, do simple press state checking there.
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 100);
    }

});
```

Comment: You can also declare 100 milliseconds as a class variable, adjusting it allows you to have a different movement speed.

Comment: I'd actually prefer to have my answer accepted rather than "thank you" =/

Answer (score 0):

Create a loop that updates the views, waits, and calls itself after it finishes waiting. Within the loop, have an animation if statement with a boolean field that move on true and does not move on false. Have the onClick method toggle the boolean field's value.

Comment: I tried that with a 100 millisecond delay, but the app still froze when I pressed the button.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
myView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
        if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            // Start your animation here
        } else if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            // Stop your animation here
        }

       return false;
    }
});
```

References:

[MotionEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_DOWN)

[OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html)

Alternatively, override `onKeyUp` and `onKeyDown` of the `View` class and check for the `KEYCODE_ENTER` `KeyEvent`

Comment: Thank you, but I tried this code about two hours ago and it didn't work.  I tried it with both a loop and by calling a thread.

Comment: @jaredad7 What "didn't work"? Did you try logging the events and seeing what's going on?

Comment: @jaredad7 Check out my 2nd suggestion to override `onKeyUp` and `onKeyDown`.